# What happens when an array is passed to the Perl length subroutine?

Tags: perl, subroutine, string-length

This is my code:

```
my @list = qw (The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy Perl programmer); 
my @list1 = qw (Sparta F R I j h df dfsd dfsdf ); 
my @list2 = qw (The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy Perl programmer); 
print length(@list), "\n"; 
print length(@list1), "\n"; 
print length(@list2), "\n";
```

The output I get:

```
2
1
2
```

What's the reason behind the output? Shouldn't it give me the length of the first element?

Comment: `scalar(@list)` is `'10'`, `scalar(@list1)` is `'9'`, `scalar(@list2)` is `'10'`.

Comment: This is part of the reason Perl 6 doesn't have a `length` subroutine or method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very well documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) and [here](http://perlmaven.com/length-of-an-array)

> The length function always works on strings and it creates SCALAR
>   context for its parameters. Hence if we pass an array as a parameter,
>   that array will be placed in SCALAR context and it will return the
>   number of elements in it.

Calling [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) on an array **returns the length of the number of elements** in the array.

Thus:

- A 10-element array `length(@list)` returns `2` (`length(10) == 2`)
- A 9-element array `length(@list1)` returns `1` (`length(9) == 1`)

Comment: and then the `length` function will return the length of the count of the number of elements in the array. `length(@array_with_0_to_9_elem) => 1`, `length(@array_with_10_to_99_elem) => 2`, ...

Answer (score 7):

The array in this context is evaluated as its length count. Since the first array contains 10 elements, then the length() function gets the string "10" as its parameter and returns 2.

The second array is of length count 9 which is 1 character long so length returns 1.